# One word for "happily surprised"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there one word for “happily surprised”?

Comment: Serendipity could be a good word

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a word meaning unexpected pleasure?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95980/is-there-a-word-meaning-unexpected-pleasure)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider *[thrilled](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thrill#Verb)* (suddenly excited, given great pleasure), *[elated](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/elated)* (made happy and excited; delighted; pleased), *[overjoyed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overjoy)* (given great joy, delight or pleasure).

Comment: I wonder whether these properly convey the element of surprise that OP intends.  I understand that *thrill* does cover *sudden excitement* but when I use the phrase *happily surprised* I intend to say that I was not expecting to be happy about something. *I was happily surprised to find that my team made the delivery on time.*  I agree that your suggestions drop right in to my example sentence, but it loses the element of surprise, and so, I think, changes the meaning slightly.

Comment: I agree, but in my shock, dismay, hurt and amazement at finding *amazed* already accepted as the answer, collapsed and was unable to spell out any finer points like that.

Answer (score 4):

Although often used (and sometimes abused), ***amazed*** fulfils the need quite well. Its literal meaning is 'astonishment, wonder.'

Comment: I'm amazed how quickly this answer was accepted!  Definitely not a happy surprise, either.

Comment: @jwpat7 I'm unhappily surprised at your comments, amazed even (in the abused sense). Hope I can please more on another occasion!

Comment: Ok. "Unaccepted" for now. Let's see what the other answers are.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with something like *[wonderment](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wonderment?show=0&t=1343933630)*:

> 2: astonishment, surprise

Answer (score 3):

Ken Dodd has the catchphrase “How tickled I am,” but has never been accused of using a formal register.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest *[gobsmacked](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/gobsmacked)*.

> Utterly astonished; astounded

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

It enjoys more use in the U.K. than in the U.S., but may suit.

Comment: Being in the U.S., I'm largely unfamiliar with _gobsmacked_. After a bit of preliminary research, it seems like the word _can_ be used to describe happy surpise, but it can also be used to describe being astonished after being blindsided by some unwelcome news. Is that true?

Comment: U.S. based, I will look to our British colleagues to comment.

Comment: In the US I've seen it a lot in videos and books, always with a sense like *flabbergasted*. The meaning shown in [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gobsmack) is "To astonish".  From etymonline, *[gobsmack](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=gobsmack)* is "U.K. slang, from gob “mouth” + p.p. of smack", before 1990, so essentially "a smack (sharp blow; a slap) in the mouth".

Comment: The general UK view of 'gobsmacked' is that it is an unattractive word to be avoided, the language of fake tans and minimum vocabulary.

Answer (score -1):

*Awestruck* or *amazed* — the closest to what you want.