# Word for a moment of unexpected emotion?

Tags: meaning

I can't seem to find anything, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Good emotion? Bad? What kinds of things inspire these moments? What's an example sentence you would use the word in? Help us help you!

Comment: A good emotion, a feeling of certain happiness when looking back on the past.

Comment: Better to [edit] such details into your question, so everyone will see them. Also, I want to say *wistful*, but that isn't quite right.

Comment: Madeleine moment?

Comment: this thread may be of interest http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76879/one-word-for-happily-surprised

Answer (score 1):

How about "epiphanous?"  Hopefully your emotive moment was revelatory, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [**nostalgia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nostalgia), based on your comment:

> A good emotion, a feeling of certain happiness when looking back on
>   the past.

"Nostalgia is a sentimentality for the past, typically for a period or place with happy personal associations."